Apex - Calculating a bi-weekly date based on inputs
I have an invocable that I plan to use that can help let a flow user choose to execute a process only every other week based on their inputs of "Current Day of the Week" (string), and a Start Date.
So if someone were to input 'Monday' and choose a start date of 5/1/2024, then the next time the flow element should return true would be when the flow runs on 5/15/2024.
I have 1 method that should get the next occurrence of a specified day of the week:
// Helper method to find the next occurrence of the specified day of the week
@TestVisible
private static Date getNextDayOfWeek(Date fromDate, String dayOfWeek) {
    
    Integer targetDay = getDayOfWeekAsInteger(dayOfWeek);
    
    DateTime dateTimeVar = DateTime.newInstance(fromDate.year(), fromDate.month(), fromDate.day());
    
    Integer currentDay = Integer.valueOf(dateTimeVar.format('u')); // 'u' gives the digit day of the week
    
    Integer daysToAdd = targetDay - currentDay;

    if (daysToAdd < 0) {
        daysToAdd += 7;
    }

    return fromDate.addDays(daysToAdd);
}

And another helper method to try and calculate the next run date:
// Helper method to calculate the next run date based on start date and day of the week
public static Date calculateNextRunDate(Date startDate, String dayOfWeek, Date today) {
    Date nextDayOfWeek = getNextDayOfWeek(today, dayOfWeek);

    // Calculate days between start date and next occurrence of the target day
    Integer daysBetween = startDate.daysBetween(nextDayOfWeek);

    
    // Adjust the next run date to ensure it's on a bi-weekly schedule
    
    while (Math.mod(daysBetween, 14) != 0) {
        nextDayOfWeek = nextDayOfWeek.addDays(7);
        daysBetween = startDate.daysBetween(nextDayOfWeek);
    }
    
    

    return nextDayOfWeek;
    
}

The problem is using Math.mod in a loop like that causes Apex cpu limits.
Is there an easier approach to this using Apex (or any other method)?

Unless I'm missing something here, the issue isn't so much that you're using Math.mod() in a loop, but more that you have an infinite loop. If daysBetween is not a multiple of 7, you'd never get to a multiple of 14 by adding 7. Might be worthwhile to set up a counter and a debug to see just how many times your loop is running.

As I said in my comment, the issue here is actually that you have an infinite loop.
If you pass in a startDate that isn't the same day of the week that you pass in for dayOfWeek, then daysBetween will not be a multiple of 7. Because of that, and because you only ever add 7 days in your loop, you'll never get out of the loop.
The quick fix here would be to call getNextDayOfWeek(startDate, dayOfWeek);, store that as a new variable, then use that instead of startDate when you call daysBetween().
public static Date calculateNextRunDate(Date startDate, String dayOfWeek, Date today) {
    Date nextDayOfWeek = getNextDayOfWeek(today, dayOfWeek);

    // If startDate isn't on the target day of the week, it'd lead to an infinite loop
    // Call getNextDayOfWeek() to ensure that doesn't happen
    Date nextStartDate = getNextDayOfWeek(startDate, dayOfWeek);

    // Need to use nextStartDate here to avoid the infinite loop (if we were
    //   still using a loop)
    Integer daysBetween = nextStartDate.daysBetween(nextDayOfWeek);

    // Now that we know that nextStartDate and nextDayOfWeek are both on the same day of
    //   the week, they're either a multiple of 7 or 14 days apart
    // So the most we'll need to do is add 7 days one time.
    // I.e. this loop can become an if (or a ternary)
    //while (Math.mod(daysBetween, 14) != 0) {
    if(Math.mod(daysBetween, 14) != 0) {
        nextDayOfWeek = nextDayOfWeek.addDays(7);

        // Need to use nextStartDate here to avoid the infinite loop (if we were
        //   still using a loop)
        //daysBetween = nextStartDate.daysBetween(nextDayOfWeek);
    }
    
    return nextDayOfWeek;
}

Some other notes for other people looking at this:
DateTime dateTimeVar = fromDate runs into some timezone auto-conversion issues (being one day in the past for people in UTC -X:XX timezones), and DateTime dateTimeVar = DateTime.newInstance(fromDate.year(), fromDate.month(), fromDate.day()) avoids those issues.
Using dateTimeVar.format('u') sidesteps the issue of some countries using Sunday as the start of the week and others using Monday as the start of the week

thinking a little more on this, since calling getNextDayOfWeek() on startDate ensures that Math.mod(daysBetween, 14) will always return 0 or 7, we can eliminate the loop/if/ternary entirely. nextDayOfWeek = nextDayOfWeek.addDays(Math.mod(daysBetween, 14)); will always do the right thing (at the cost of being a bit less readable).
